# using case statement to read from a variable/file while creating a MENU

Tags: linux, files, variable, case

```
read -p 'enter your choice [ 1-5 ]' choice
        case $choice in

        1)abcrequest

        2)defresponse

        3)afgRequestReply

        4)FSfReply

        5)ghjrequest
```

I want the case statement to read these numbers from a file and then after entering my choice it should go to that choice.

I hope you understand my query.

Comment: You should check the proper syntax for `case`. What exactly is your question, though? And what do you mean when you say you want to "read these numbers from a file"? What's in the file?

Comment: the file has 1)abcrequest

        2)defresponse

        3)afgRequestReply

        4)FSfReply

        5)ghjrequest

Answer (score 0):

Using a `select` loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

list=~/tmp/list.txt

PS3='enter your choice: '

while read -r index element; do
    _list[index]=$element
done < <(awk -F\) '{print $1,$2}' "$list")

select i in "${_list[@]}"; do
    case $i in
        *)  echo "Choice is ${_list[REPLY]}";;
    esac
done
```

---

`list` should be set to the path of the file containing your menu.  In my case it contains:

```
$ cat list.txt
1)abcrequest
2)defresponse
3)afgRequestReply
4)FSfReply
5)ghjrequest
```

`PS3` will be the prompt used by `select`

We then look through each line in `list` and separate the number from its value and build an array with that.  `_list` will contain:

```
_list=([1]="abcrequest" [2]="defresponse" [3]="afgRequestReply" [4]="FSfReply" [5]="ghjrequest")
```

Now `select` will build a menu with each item in `_list`.  `REPLY` will contain the number of your selection so using that we can do something with the value of that index in `_list`.  (You could also just use `$i` directly though)

Note: this list will continuously prompt unless your code contains an `exit` or `break` statement, or if you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

```
$ ./script.sh
1) abcrequest
2) defresponse
3) afgRequestReply
4) FSfReply
5) ghjrequest
enter your choice: 4
Choice is FSfReply
enter your choice: 5
Choice is ghjrequest
enter your choice: 2
Choice is defresponse
enter your choice: ^C
```

Comment: thanky you so much , this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Hi Jesse_b, can you tell why have you used done < <(awk -F\) , why is there a space between those redirections , why not << .

Comment: @ShivamMalhotra: It's called [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)